# Reduce-Reduce Conflicts

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

how to eliminate the reduce-reduce conflicts of the following yacc file:

```
MATH_EXPRESSION   :   MATH_EXPRESSION PLUS MATH_EXPRESSION
                    | MINUS MATH_EXPRESSION   %prec UMINUS
                    | MATH_EXPRESSION MINUS MATH_EXPRESSION
                    | MATH_EXPRESSION MULTIPLY MATH_EXPRESSION
                    | MATH_EXPRESSION DIVIDE MATH_EXPRESSION
                    | MATH_EXPRESSION REMAINDER MATH_EXPRESSION
                    | MATH_EXPRESSION POWER MATH_EXPRESSION
                    | BRACKET_OPEN MATH_EXPRESSION BRACKET_CLOSE
                    | OPERAND
                    ;



LOGICAL_EXPRESSION  : LOGICAL_EXPRESSION LOGICAL_AND LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION LOGICAL_OR LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_NOT LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION COMPARE_EQUAL LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION COMPARE_NOT_EQUAL LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION COMPARE_GREATER LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION COMPARE_LESS LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION COMPARE_GREATER_EQUAL LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION COMPARE_LESS_EQUAL LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                      | BRACKET_OPEN LOGICAL_EXPRESSION BRACKET_CLOSE
                      | OPERAND
                      ;


OPERAND           : NUMBER
                  | IDENTIFIER
                  ;



MATH_OR_LOGICAL_EXPRESSION  : MATH_EXPRESSION
                            | LOGICAL_EXPRESSION
                            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To see why there is a conflict, consider an input that simply consists of an identifier. Is that a `MATH_EXPRESSION` or a `LOGICAL_EXPRESSION`? That's impossible for the parser to decide because it fits both rules.

What you should do is have one expression rule that contains both logical and arithmetic operators. Distinguishing between types generally can't be handled at the parsing level, you'll need to do that in the type checker.